# Errors in ggplot and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, rstudio, plotly

When I try graphing my double bar graph using ggplot on r- shiny using plotly's interface, the double bar graph is getting data from random places and does not properly graph the plot.

I have used this interface on single bar plots and it has worked perfectly and correctly displays the data and graph but with double bar plots, it just uses random data? The regular ggplot plot is fine but when I transform it to a plotly it screws up.

```
output$tvpn <- renderPlotly({

     mpolfinal4$Partner.Name= factor(mpolfinal4$Partner.Name,
                                       levels=names(sort(table(mpolfinal4$Partner.Name),
                                                    decreasing=TRUE)))
     tv =  ggplot(mpolfinal4, aes(x =Partner.Name, fill=Domain.Name)) +
             geom_bar(colour="black") + 
             theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) + 
             ggtitle("Total Views by Partner Name, and Domain Name")

     out = ggplotly(tv)
     out
  })
```

Has anyone experienced this issue/know how to fix it?

Comment: Could you supply some data (an example dataframe) to reproduce the error and post it at github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues? Thanks!

Comment: https://gyazo.com/50f22068c74e92fa440a39c583c311ec

vs
https://gyazo.com/a499fa0a700cd154c416db4a6fa14992

First link is for the plotly graph, unordered, wrong numbers